# How to locate all google spreadsheets which is created through google sheet api

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using googleapis to create a google sheet. My code

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const keys = require("./credentials.json");

var spreadsheetId = null;
var gsapi = null;
const title = "SheetExample1!";

createConnection = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = new google.auth.JWT(
      keys.client_email,
      null,
      keys.private_key,
      ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
    );

    client.authorize((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        gsapi = google.sheets({
          version: "v4",
          auth: client,
        });
        console.log("Connection Created Successfully");
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
};

createSheet = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const resource = {
      properties: {
        title,
      },
    };
    gsapi.spreadsheets.create(
      {
        resource,
        fields: "spreadsheetId",
      },
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Sheet Created with spreadsheetId============",
            response.data.spreadsheetId
          );
          resolve(response.data);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};

functionHelper = async () => {
  await createConnection();
  await createSheet();
};

functionHelper();
```

In response, I am getting spreadsheetId. But I have no idea where all these sheets are stored and how I can open a spreadsheet using the generated spreadsheet Id.

I checked I can't see these files inside https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/

Any suggestion?

Comment: By default all things are create in My Drive. There are advanced ways to create them in specific places. In your code, right after you create something you can get its ID or URL and later in the code you can reopen it by these item indicators. They are constant no matter where you might drag the item.

Comment: @aNewb Yes, In response I got spreadsheetUrl but How I can open it, or is any way to save that file locally on my system.?